# Sending objects in a get request

Tags: spring, spring-boot, httprequest, endpoint

I 'll explain first what I'm trying to do:
There's a service method that receives a thymeleaf template html file, process that and then transform into a pdf. The job that was assigned to me is to create an endpoint which returns the template html so the service will call that endpoint to get the html.
I don't know how to pass objects in a get request.

The code in the service method before:

```
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    
    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

    Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariable("expenseReportPdf", expenseReportPdf);
    context.setVariable("expensePdf", expensePdfList);
    context.setVariable("expenseImg", jpgFile);
    context.setVariable("amountCompanyCurrency", amountCompanyCurrency);
    context.setVariable("expenseIncurredList", expenseIncurredList);
    context.setVariable("expenseRiepiloghiList",expenseRiepiloghiList);
    context.setVariable("advancePayBigDecimal", advancePayBigDecimal);
    
    context.setVariable("dailyAllowanceList", dailyAllowanceList);
    context.setVariable("dailyAllowanceFlag", dailyAllowanceFlag.booleanValue());
    
    context.setVariable("logo",logo);
    context.setVariable("logoSmartex",logoSmartex);
    logger.debug("Logo Smartex:" + logoSmartex);
    logger.debug("Logo Company:" + logo);
    String renderedHtmlContent = templateEngine.process("template", context);
```

Firstly I moved that part in a configuration class which creates the beans necessary to return the html.

```
@Configuration
public class TemplateConfiguration {

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(htmlTemplateResolver2());
    return templateEngine;
}

// Esiste già un bean che si chiama htmlTemplateResolver
@Bean
public ClassLoaderTemplateResolver htmlTemplateResolver2() {
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setOrder(Integer.valueOf(3));
    resolver.setPrefix("templates/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);

    return resolver;
}
```

}

Then i create the endpoint which should return the html processed.

```
@GetMapping(path = "/get-template-html")
public String getTemplateHTMLEndpoint(@RequestParam("expenseReportPdf") String expenseReportPdfJSON, @RequestParam("expensePdfList") String expensePdfListJSON,
                                    @RequestParam("jpgFile") String jpgFileJSON, @RequestParam("amountCompanyCurrency") String amountCompanyCurrencyJSON,
                                    @RequestParam("expenseIncurredList") String expenseIncurredListJSON, @RequestParam("expenseRiepiloghiList") String expenseRiepiloghiListJSON,
                                    @RequestParam("advancePayBigDecimal") String advancePayBigDecimalJSON, @RequestParam("dailyAllowanceList") String dailyAllowanceListJSON,
                                    @RequestParam("dailyAllowanceFlag") String dailyAllowanceFlag, @RequestParam("logo") String logo, @RequestParam("logoSmartex") String logoSmartex) {

    // TODO convert JSON params to relative objects
    
    Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariable("expenseReportPdf", expenseReportPdf);
    context.setVariable("expensePdf", expensePdfList);
    context.setVariable("expenseImg", jpgFile);
    context.setVariable("amountCompanyCurrency", amountCompanyCurrency);
    context.setVariable("expenseIncurredList", expenseIncurredList);
    context.setVariable("expenseRiepiloghiList",expenseRiepiloghiList);
    context.setVariable("advancePayBigDecimal", advancePayBigDecimal);
    context.setVariable("dailyAllowanceList", dailyAllowanceList);
    context.setVariable("dailyAllowanceFlag", String dailyAllowanceFlag);
    context.setVariable("logo",logo);
    context.setVariable("logoSmartex",logoSmartex);

    String renderedHtmlContent = templateEngine.process("template", context);

    return renderedHtmlContent;
    
}
```

}

Finally I created a method in the service which calls the endpoint.

```
private String callGetTemplateHTMLEndPoint(ExpenseReportPdf expenseReportPdf, List<ExpensePdf> expensePdfList, List<ExpenseImg> jpgFile,
                                            BigDecimal amountCompanyCurrency, List<ExpenseIncurred> expenseIncurredList,
                                            List<ExpenseRiepiloghi> expenseRiepiloghiList, BigDecimal advancePayBigDecimal,
                                            List<DailyAllowanceDetails> dailyAllowanceList, Boolean dailyAllowanceFlag, String logo,
                                            String logoSmartex) {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    
    String JSONExpenseReportPdf = "";
    String JSONExpensePdfList = "";
    String JSONJpgFile = "";
    String JSONAmountCompanyCurrency = "";
    String JSONExpenseIncurredList = "";
    String JSONExpenseRiepiloghiList = "";
    String JSONAdvancePayBigDecimal = "";
    String JSONDailyAllowanceList = "";
    
    // Trasformo i parametri in JSON
    try {
        
        JSONExpenseReportPdf = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(expenseReportPdf);
        JSONExpensePdfList = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(expensePdfList);
        JSONJpgFile = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(jpgFile);
        JSONAmountCompanyCurrency = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(amountCompanyCurrency);
        JSONExpenseIncurredList = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(expenseIncurredList);
        JSONExpenseRiepiloghiList = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(expenseRiepiloghiList);
        JSONAdvancePayBigDecimal = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(advancePayBigDecimal);
        JSONDailyAllowanceList = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(dailyAllowanceList);
        
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    // Creo i query params coi JSON
    String params = "?";
    params += "expenseReportPdf=" + JSONExpenseReportPdf + "&";
    params += "expensePdfList=" + JSONExpensePdfList + "&";
    params += "jpgFile=" + JSONJpgFile + "&";
    params += "amountCompanyCurrency=" + JSONAmountCompanyCurrency + "&";
    params += "expenseIncurredList=" + JSONExpenseIncurredList + "&";
    params += "expenseRiepiloghiList=" + JSONExpenseRiepiloghiList + "&";
    params += "advancePayBigDecimal=" + JSONAdvancePayBigDecimal + "&";
    params += "dailyAllowanceList=" + JSONDailyAllowanceList + "&";
    params += "dailyAllowanceFlag=" + dailyAllowanceFlag + "&";
    params += "logo=" + logo + "&";
    params += "logoSmartex=" + logoSmartex;
    
    HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    HttpRequest httpRequest = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                         .uri(URI.create("http://localhost:9898/Smartex/expense-report-pdf/get-template-html" + params))
                                         .build();
    
    String templateHTML = "Problems with the request";
    
    try {
        templateHTML = httpClient.send(httpRequest, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString())
                                        .body();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    return templateHTML;
    
}
```

I don't know how to send/receive the params needed for the processing of the template, any idea?

TY

After a while I thought I could transform objects into JSON, add them as query params and then transform them back in the controller but there are 2 problems:

1. The URL is too much long (2568 characters)
2. URL contains {} and give error

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO - we don't like links here - please use formatter tool and paste your code into the question. 

May I also suggest that sending data in a get request is generally against REST guidelines and bad design? POST would be much more adequate. If you insist on ur requirement just use URL parameters

Comment: I've adjusted my request.
Isn't POST used to send data to store in database?
Yes I was thinking about transforming object into JSON and send them as query params

Comment: I don't like to send data in the url

Comment: u dnt have much of a choise - the only way to transfer objects with GET is a URL paramer - example here (https://lankydan.dev/2017/03/11/passing-data-transfer-objects-with-get-in-spring-boot). Otherwise - and correct way would be to use POST, irrelevant whether the end goal is to persist to db or not

Comment: Ok, ty. I thought wrongly GET is used to retrieve data, POST to send instead